# How to design a clean API interface?

Tags: java, api

I have a fairly simple requirement for a query API which I need to implement.

So, I need to query a datastructure and from the the client's perspective, it's like:

```
Select * where idValue=baseball and child.age<10 and child.city=Sydney
```

(and it should support any other future arguments added to the database)

Now, how can I realize this form of query in a java argument - which is clean, elegant and obvious to the user (for example use enum=idValue,age,city) etc.

My thoughts: `Map<QUERY, VALUE>` can work? But how do I specify age<10 or age>=20?

My client interface:

```
List<Child> getChildern(x);
```

Where x = the above mentioned select query.

References: [How to Design a Good API and Why it Matters](http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf)

**Usecase**: I have a backend database (application embedded) to which I want to provide access to for developers. My app populates the data but that data should be query-able by the api users. Now the dataabase is berkley db where I have a custom way of storing data objects.

Comment: Your question is too general. What data structure? And most importantly use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your question is just a touch too general, an actual answer would take a lot more space than would be appropriate in a SO answer. However I recommend you take a peek at Spring-Ldap's Fileter API which more or less does what you need. It might contain more that you want to implement here, but just focus on the basic idea and go from there, because, what ever you might say about the Spring stuff, it certanly has good clean simple APIs:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.2.0/api/spring-ldap/org/springframework/ldap/filter/package-summary.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/basic.html#basic-filters

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simple you could do something like this:

```
List<Child> getChildern(String idValue, String ageConstraint, String city);
```

You would have to mention for example that you support "=","<" and ">" characters on start of the ageConstraint. You would parse that in the method.

It depends a lot on who is using the API to define how strict or flexible you should make it. Also how easy it is to change it later. This was simplest one that doesn't require much extra work. It's better to make it more restrictive to avoid bugs.

Comment: But what if 2 new data types for children are added? I need to account for that too. Updated that in the question.

Comment: @John How about taking List<Constraint> as a parameter and then implement IdConstraint, AgeConstraint and CityConstraint that are subclasses of Constraint. You can add more later without breaking existing implementation. This way you still have the control of what they can do (security consideration).